# Charset issue with Base64 encoding

Tags: ruby, encoding, base64

I'm trying to encode/decode a simple string...
Here it is:

```
Base64.encode64("FUOdM6Tgl;FUOK4X2ZT;u6OUm;MAK HOLZ GmbH & Co KG;fuo16;pellet@makholz.com;pellet@makholz.at;AT69685557;IT")
```

The resulting value is this:

```
"RlVPZE02VGdsO0ZVT0s0WDJaVDt1Nk9VbTtNQUsgSE9MWiBHbWJIICYgQ28g\nS0c7ZnVvMTY7cGVsbGV0QG1ha2hvbHouY29tO3BlbGxldEBtYWtob2x6LmF0\nO0FUNjk2ODU1NTc7SVQ=\n"
```

And If I decode it from the console, I correctly get the original string:

```
Base64.decode64("RlVPZE02VGdsO0ZVT0s0WDJaVDt1Nk9VbTtNQUsgSE9MWiBHbWJIICYgQ28g\nS0c7ZnVvMTY7cGVsbGV0QG1ha2hvbHouY29tO3BlbGxldEBtYWtob2x6LmF0\nO0FUNjk2ODU1NTc7SVQ=\n")
# => "FUOdM6Tgl;FUOK4X2ZT;u6OUm;MAK HOLZ GmbH & Co KG;fuo16;pellet@makholz.com;pellet@makholz.at;AT69685557;IT"
```

Now.. the values I get using some online tools are different. It seems a charset problem. How should I fix it?

---

edit:

Well, I found the problem. The encoded strings contain "\n" chars. So I decided to do this: Base64.encode64(str).gsub(/\n/, '')

Comment: I don't see any non 7-bit ASCII in your example. Are you talking about other strings? [This example site](https://www.base64encode.org) produces identical output for your input.

Comment: Which specific online tools? What specific results are they giving you?

Comment: We can't really answer this without more information. However, if you're having issues with compatibility with other tools, you may want to try [`Base64.strict_encode64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-strict_encode64).

Comment: Well, I found the problem. The encoded strings contain "\n" chars. So I decided to do this: Base64.encode64(str).gsub(/\n/, '')